# Low value capacitors on PCB

Tags: filter, capacitance

Why do we avoid using capacitors of low values ​​like capacitors of 1pF during electronics circuit design?

What is the problem that they can pose at the level of PCB routing?

Comment: if I rephrase the correct answer below, your traces have more capacitance, and since they have different lengths and widths and all, it's hard to predict, and you simply don't need them that small. For example, when you choose capacitors for crystal oscillators (they are around 10-20pf actually) the rule of thumb is to assume trace capacitance of ~5pF (and crystal traces are supposed to be short). It's the only common use for caps that small. Usually you decouple every chip with 0.1uF (that's 100,000 times 1pf!) and bulk caps are 1uF-10uF

Comment: Yes.  As an exercise, do two things: assume a trace that's above a ground plane.  Let the spacing be 1.6mm (i.e., common board thickness and a 2-layer board).  Compute the area of that trace needed to get a 1pF capacitor, ignoring fringing.  Now compute the size of the square patch to get that same capacitance.  Now compare that to the size of common components.  Then repeat that exercise for a 4-layer board (i.e., a layer spacing of 1.6mm / 3).

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 9):

They get swamped by the PCB parasitic capacitance unless you know what you're doing. So for decoupling you do not need discrete caps that small, and when you do need a specific values that small (like for oscillators or amplifiers) then you must take into account the effects of the PCB and design accordingly.

Comment: In general, if you find you need 1pF caps in a design, it's an indication that either you're trying to do things at too high an impedance, or that you need to be designing using transmission line techniques.

Comment: Yes. The whole 'unless you know what you're doing is a whole can of worms, which I feel should be adressed as well. Signal traces can have 50-100pf / m of capacitance, or even higher for *thicc* traces. For an interesting application, check out "What's All This Femtoampere Stuff, Anyhow?" by Bob pease. where they work around capacitances and leakage currents.

Answer (score 3):

Caps of 1pF are used in microwave parts where the impedance is around 130 Ohms @ 1GHz as you can see on the graph.

But for low f even at 10 MHz you must expect traces near each other to produce more than this . Below geometry is  0.66 pF /cm

Keep in mind the spectrum of a square wave is f-3dB=0.35/Tr rise time from 10 to 90% so parasitic crosstalk may affect logic as well as linear circuits when the bandwidth of the chip is considered.

[image]

Here is a graphical relationship of impedances, resonance intersections and their impedance vs f for LC and R

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For bypassing, values that small (~1pF) are not useful, at least at the board level, due to the board trace inductance. What’s more important is to consider the capacitor’s non-ideal behavior as an RLC element and design accordingly. For example, alternate geometries that reduce the capacitors’ equivalent series inductance like reverse aspect, multi-terminal, or feed through, when used with good layout technique, greatly improve high-frequency performance.

For filter design, sensitivity to layout parasitics gets very large as the L and C values get very small. While it’s possible to use ~1pF values in filters (and I’ve built products like this), the whole physical system must be modeled and validated in prototype to check performance. Because of this, RF designers get very creative and fussy about materials and design rules to make this happen.